# I am getting NoSuchMethod found

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am new in spring + hibernate. While I am running my project I am getting the below exception :

```
17:44:25,044 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-4) UT005023: Exception handling request to /Spring-hibernate-integration-helloworld/saveUser.html: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.Session.connection()Ljava/sql/Connection;
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.triggerAfterCompletionWithError(DispatcherServlet.java:1303) [spring-webmvc-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:977) [spring-webmvc-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893) [spring-webmvc-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) [spring-webmvc-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872) [spring-webmvc-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707) [jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) [spring-webmvc-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) [jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:86) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:248) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:77) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:167) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:199) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:761) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.Session.connection()Ljava/sql/Connection;
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.getJdbcConnection(HibernateJpaDialect.java:91) [spring-orm-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar:3.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:348) [spring-orm-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar:3.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373) [spring-tx-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:427) [spring-tx-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:276) [spring-tx-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) [spring-tx-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207) [spring-aop-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy130.saveUser(Unknown Source)
```

I have used below jar :

```
activation-1.0.2.jar
antlr-2.7.6.jar
aopalliance-1.0.jar
asm-1.5.3.jar
asm-attrs-1.5.3.jar
cglib-2.1_3.jar
commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar
commons-collections-2.1.1.jar
commons-digester-1.8.jar
commons-email-1.0.jar
commons-fileupload-1.1.1.jar
commons-io-1.1.jar
commons-lang-2.5.jar
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
dom4j-1.6.1.jar
dumbster-1.6.jar
ehcache-1.2.3.jar
hibernate-3.2.6.ga.jar
javassist-3.4.GA.jar
jaxb-api-2.1.jar
jaxb-impl-2.1.3.jar
jaxen-1.1.1.jar
jdom-1.0.jar
jstl-1.2.jar
jta-1.1.jar
log4j-1.2.14.jar
lucene-core-2.3.2.jar
lucene-highlighter-2.0.0.jar
mail-1.4.jar
mysql-connector-java-5.0.5.jar
persistence-api-1.0.jar
quartz-1.5.2.jar
slf4j-api-1.5.6.jar
slf4j-log4j12-1.5.6.jar
spring-aop-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-beans-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-core-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-expression-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-jdbc-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-orm-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-tx-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-webmvc-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar
stax-api-1.0-2.jar
validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar
xalan-2.6.0.jar
xercesImpl-2.6.2.jar
xml-apis-1.3.02.jar
xmlParserAPIs-2.6.2.jar
xom-1.0.jar
```

Why I am getting the above exception? Please help

Comment: most likely you have incompatible library versions.  e.g. the version of hibernate you using is not compatible with the library using it.  most likely, your hibernate version is too old.

Answer (score 2):

This error means that the method `org.hibernate.Session.connection()` which returns an object of type `java.sql.Connection` cannot be found in the hibernate version retrieved from the context `ClassLoader`. In your case, you use Hibernate `3.2.6.ga` which contains this method, knowing that this method has been removed since Hibernate `4.0`, I suspect that it actually uses the version of hibernate bundled into wildfly.

You should upgrade your version of `spring-orm` in order to be compatible with the version of hibernate of `wildfly`. Indeed `spring-orm 3.0.1.RELEASE` depends on `hibernate-core 3.3.1.GA` (as you can see [here](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.springframework%7Cspring-orm%7C3.0.1.RELEASE%7Cjar)) such that it tries to access to a non existing method which is the root cause of your conflict here.